# How do I install .Net3.5 on Win8 quietly as part of an installer?

Tags: .net, wix, silent-installer

Pretty much as the title.  I'm using WiX to create an installer and need to include .Net 3.5 web installer as a payload.

I've got it working on Win7 and Vista using /q, but on Win8 the 'Add a Feature' functionality seems to override the web installer. Is there a way to force the web installer, or cause add a feature to activate quietly?

Comment: .NET 3.5 is already included in Win 8, you just need to enable it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [dism](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744311%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) tool?

Something like

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /quiet /norestart
```

might work.

Answer (score 0):

in your InstallCommand attribute, `"/passive /norestart"` should force the .NET installer to run quietly and as part of your WiX installer without restarting. This is what I use when including .NET in any of my packages and it works like a charm.

Hope this helps.